# Angular ui router template not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular and ui-router with Rails.

I can't get this template to show for the life of me.  I know others have asked similar questions, but I can't seem to find the issue.

The URL I am hitting is http://localhost:3000/users/[username]

**angular_app.js**

```
project.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('user', {
        url: "users/:username",
        views: {
            "user": {
                templateUrl: 'users/videos.html',
                controller: 'UserController'
            }
        }
     });
}]);
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<div>
    <h1>Videos</h1>
    <div ui-view="user" ng-controller="UserController">
    <!-- Should get replaced by videos.html template -->
    </div>
</div>
```

videos.html (template in `app/assets/javascript/templates/users`)

```
<h1>videos template</h1>
```

I also have a controller called `UserController`.

I would expect the "videos template" text to come up in show.html.erb.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need ng-controller on the ui-view `<div>`, it's already defined in the route.

Also, is your template file named video.html or videos.html? You mention both.